# Three buttons among each other using leaflet

Tags: html, css, button, responsive, tailwind-css

I am to create the following button panel.
The three buttons should be directly below each other, each button should have an image (I1,I2,I3), there should be a radius at the top and bottom and a separator line between the buttons. There should also be a small shadow effect around the button.

But now I have problems to place the buttons in a way that they are directly below each other and fill a DIV which has a certain responsive size (buttons full div width and each button 1/3 of the DIV height). Also, I couldn't manage to insert the dividing lines between the buttons yet.

my code so far: [enter link description here](https://jsfiddle.net/owarxhfp/)

```
    <div class="border rounded-lg border-1 border-white h-32 w-11 z-1000">
  <div class="border-white">
    <button
      class="block text-center h-1/3 w-full m-0 p-0 bg-gray-lighter z-1000"
    >
      <img class="items-center" src="~/assets/resize.png" />
    </button>
    <div class="divide-y-4 divide-yellow-600 divide-solid" />
    <button
      class="block text-center h-1/3 w-full m-0 p-0 bg-gray-lighter z-1000"
    >
      <span class="text-red-dark">+</span>
    </button>
    <div class="divide-y-4 divide-red-dark divide-solid w-full" />
    <button
      class="block text-center h-1/3 w-full m-0 p-0 bg-gray-lighter z-1000"
    >
      <span class="text-red-dark">-</span>
    </button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Glad about any help!

[image]

Comment: try to using `flexbox`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use flexbox with [flex-col](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/flex-direction#column)

```html
<div class="flex flex-col bg-white rounded-lg shadow-md divide-y-2 divide-gray-200">
  <button class="w-12 h-12">l1</button>
  <button class="w-12 h-12">l2</button>
  <button class="w-12 h-12">l3</button>
</div>
```

https://play.tailwindcss.com/QPv7j1MCVD

Comment: this worked best for me! God bless you! ;) Much thanks to all other comments too :)

Answer (score 0):

done check here [fiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/k3brwyhv/)

hope it works

```
<div class="border-white" style="">
        <div class="divide-y-4 divide-yellow-600 divide-solid" style="
    height: 150px;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: space-evenly;">
        <button class="block text-center h-1/3 w-full m-0 p-0 bg-gray-lighter z-1000">
          <span class="text-red-dark">$</span>
        </button><hr style="
    border: 2px solid black;
    width: 70px;
    border-radius: 40px;
    margin: 0 auto;
">
<button class="block text-center h-1/3 w-full m-0 p-0 bg-gray-lighter z-1000">
          <span class="text-red-dark">+</span>
        </button>
<hr style="
    border: 2px solid black;
    width: 70px;
    border-radius: 40px;
    margin: 0 auto;
">
        <button class="block text-center h-1/3 w-full m-0 p-0 bg-gray-lighter z-1000">
          <span class="text-red-dark">-</span>
        </button>
    </div>
    </div>
```